# Assign two variables to each other without duplicates | Create groups of two in R

Tags: r, combinations

I'd like to randomly assign members to each other. However, the problem seems trickier than originally expected. `combn`and `sample`don'r work because of duplicates. If a member is assigned to another one, it can't end up with a third identity.

I've a very rude workaround to illustrate what I want:

```
groupmembers <- 10
set <- 1:groupmembers
df <- data.frame(g1=set, g2=NA)

for(i in 1:(nrow(df)/2)){
    set.seed(137)
    draw <- sample(set, 1)
    while(draw==i) draw <- sample(set, 1)

    df[i,2] <- draw

    df[which(df[,1]==draw),2] <- df$g1[i]

    set <- set[-which(set %in% as.numeric(df[i,]))]
}

   g1 g2
1   1  7
2   2  8
3   3  6
4   4  9
5   5 10
6   6  3
7   7  1
8   8  2
9   9  4
10 10  5
```

With this `set.seed` I get what I want. However, if I change `set.seed` I may or may not end up with `NA` in my `df`. Is there a more elegant solution?
The output can be a `list` of pairs or a `data.frame` etc.

Thanks

**Edit**

I may not only end up with `NA` but also with non-mirrored pairs, which I'd like to prevent.

Comment: Can you show what the expected result would look like?

Comment: Are the matches intentionally "mirrored" (e.g. 1/7 and 7/1)?

Comment: I just did. The expected result should look like above (it does so with that loop and that `set.seed`). Every pair of numbers occurs twice: `{3,6}` and ´{6,3}`

Comment: Jop, they should be mirrored. Think of it as persons. Person 1 talks to person 7 (and 7 to 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
groupmembers <- 10
set <- 1:groupmembers

df <- data.frame(g1 = set, g2 = set)
while(any(df[,1] == df[,2])){
    df[,2] <- sample(df[,2])
}
```

**Edit:**

Or if you want only want to get "equal pairs" (e.g. 10/2 & 2/10) you might try this:

```
group1 <- set[sample(set,length(set)/2)]
group2 <- set[!set %in% group1]

df <- data.frame(g1 = c(group1,group2), f2 = c(group2,group1))

   g1 f2
1  10  2
2   3  4
3   7  5
4   9  6
5   1  8
6   2 10
7   4  3
8   5  7
9   6  9
10  8  1
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to prevent. For example, number 2 is in a set with 9 and with 10. However: Every pair of numbers should occur only twice: `{3,6}` and ´{6,3}`